# Is it possible for a field that is part of a composite key to be a foreign key referencing a primary key in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I am trying to model a database and I have two tables: Cell_Information and Cell_Stats
In Cell_Information, Cell_ID is the primary key.

In Cell_Stats, Cell_ID and Timestamp are a composite primary key.

is it possible for Cell_Stats.Cell_ID to be a foreign key while also being part of the composite key?

Comment: The answer is "yes" -- you can easily try it.

Comment: If you are having trouble with it, show us the specific SQL that is causing trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible for [a particular column] to be a foreign key while also being part of the composite key?

Yes.

That was easy.  If you are having trouble making it work, please ask another question.